# When to use «вдвое/втрое/etc» rather than «в два/три/etc раза»

Tags: словоупотребление

> Говорят, что это в самом деле были огромные медведи **в два раза больше** любого человека!
>
> Говорят, что это в самом деле были огромные медведи **вдвое больше** любого человека!

I'm a bit fuzzy on when I should use "в два/три/etc раза" and when I should go for "вдвое/втрое/etc".

Answer (score 2):

Собирательные числительные (вдвое, втрое, etc.) are a bit more colloquial but totally acceptable in everyday speech and in literature. 
Both forms are correct and common.

The main difference is that "**в X раз**" is not limited in the number of times, while собирательные числительные go from 2 to 10. You can say "Акции компании за несколько лет выросли в цене в 12 раз", But you cannot say "в двенадцатеро". In practice only "вдвое и втрое" is widely used, starting with "вчетверо" and up it's more likely to hear and read "**в X раз**".

Much like in English you can say **twice** and **thrice** (and the latter is rarely used) and that's it. After that you just use '**X times**", though you can say in some instances that something has doubled, tripled or quadrupled. Again, can only go to four. You of course can go with **Xfold** as high as you want, but it's rarely used outside of articles and books and it's yet a different form. So realistically after 3 in English "**X times**" is used.

Also the bears that are twice as large as human are extremely tiny ones. The truly huge ones are 6-8 times bigger. Kodiak and Kamchatka brown bears reach over 650 kilos and 3 meters in height :)

Comment: Ooops, I had in mind less-intimidating bears seen in Japan when coming up with this example. The exclamation point at the end may be unwarranted, then. :)

Comment: 3 метра - это меньше, чем вдвое больше человека по росту. :))))) But here I remember the anecdote "и это только глаз".

Comment: We say сложите лист бумаги вчетверо. I think, it is grammatically possible to use it with almost any numeral, but it is inconvenient to say ввосьмеро. Mostly we use вдвое, втрое, вчетверо.

Answer (score 1):

**«В два/три/etc раза»** is a more formal and neutral option:

> Рост медведей этого вида в два-три раза превышает человеческий.

**«Вдвое/втрое/etc»** has a greater emotional content, indicating the significance of the difference, and is more colloquial:

> Я вчера такого медведя видел... Он вдвое, а может даже втрое больше любого человека!

Comment: "has a greater emotional content, indicating the significance of the difference" - I disagree so I down-vote. "Я вчера такого медведя видел. Он в два раза, а то и раза в три больше любого человека"! - is equally emotional whatever it actually means.

Comment: the emphatic contamination or perception thereof may stem from the fact that this form is more characterisic of colloquial language (so i assume) than of the written one

Answer (score 0):

If you know the consrtuction with вдвое, втрое, use it in your speech. It sounds really natural and is closer to native speaking.

Whereas there exists

> двукратно больше, трёхкратно больше, четырёхкратно больше

and that is really old-fashioned and can hardly be heard nowadays, but will be well-understood by Russian speakers.

В два, три, четыре раза is more neutral.